# How can I put text within horizontal bar chart data points using Highcharts as well as adding text underneath each data point? Example below:

Tags: highcharts

[Here is what I am going for, disregard the pointer on top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/266PO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `annotations` module:

```
annotations: [{
    labels: [{
        borderRadius: 0,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        style: {
            color: '#000'
        },
        point: {
            xAxis: 0,
            yAxis: 0,
            x: 0,
            y: 15
        },
        y: -130,
        text: 'Col de la Joux'
    }]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/eb9k5o7m/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module